# AT24CXX IC Card unexplained variables

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, hardware

I'm working with a C++ card dispenser hardware API on C#, I've done the easy parts dll imports etc and the documentation is pretty well done. However, there is two input variable I can't figure out here is the docs

```
/**
 *  AT24CXX IC card read data, must power on.
 *
 *  @param [in] ComHandle Port handle(> 0).
 *  @param [in] CardType Card type, see the value below.
 *  @param [in] RLEN Data length of reading.
 *  @param [in] ADDRH High byte of card memory address.
 *  @param [in] ADDRL Low byte of card memory address.
 *  @param [out] ReadData buffer to store return read result. 
 *  @param [out] ERR_Code buffer to store API function error code. please reference to @ref APIErrorCode.
 *  
 *  CardType value:
 * | Type     | Type Value   | Memory Size  |   Address Index Range
 * | ------   |------------- | ------------ |  --------------------
 * | AT24C01  |    0x30      |  128 byte    |   addr = 0x0000-0x007F
 * | AT24C02  |    0x31          |  256 byte    |   addr = 0x0000-0x00FF
 * | AT24C04  |    0x32          |  512 byte    |   addr = 0x0000-0x01FF
 * | AT24C08  |    0x33          |  1K byte     |   addr = 0x0000-0x03FF
 * | AT24C16  |    0x34          |  2K byte     |   addr = 0x0000-0x07FF
 * | AT24C32  |    0x35          |  4K byte     |   addr = 0x0000-0x0FFF
 * | AT24C64  |    0x36          |  8K byte     |   addr = 0x0000-0x1FFF
 *
 *  @return  == 0, success, != 0, failed. please reference to @ref APIReturn.
 *
 *  @note the card memory address meaning is the address = (low byte + hight byte * 256).
 *
 */
int APIENTRY WBCM7200_AT24XXRead(HANDLE ComHandle, BYTE CardType, BYTE RLEN, BYTE ADDRH, BYTE ADDRL, BYTE ReadData[], BYTE *ERR_Code);
```

the variable I can't figure out is ADDRH and ADDRL. I've researched High and low bits in C++ and C# to no progress, in any case, see my import below

```
[DllImport(CardDispenserLibrary, EntryPoint = "WBCM7200_AT24XXRead", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int ReadCard(int comHandle, byte cardType, byte rlen, byte addrh, byte addrl, byte[] readData, out byte error);
```

I have called the function with all posible combinations of ADDRH and ADDRL and the return is -1 and out byte is 4 which is conviniently missing from the mentioned APIErrorCode. I have a 2K card. What are those values?

Comment: Looks like it wants you to split a 16-bit address into 2 8-bit numbers. Can you show how you call it?

Comment: comHandle should be IntPtr (HANDLE is a void*, so it adapts to bitness)

Comment: I came to discover that the machine has other small machines inside so before attempting to read you have to call powerOnOff, then CardScan and then read(WBCM7200_AT24XXRead)